# Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'Yb' of undefined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

**Something has gone wrong. Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'Yb' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:lassoCommunity}. Please try again.**

Not used `$A.getCallback()` in my *controller* and *helper*.

Getting this error after some months of deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@itzmukeshy7, this error is coming after salesforce winter 17 release and cause of this issue is Access Check violations that means in your code  you are trying to access some attributes which are not defined by  tag.
Please see the link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Something-went-wrong-error-in-community-builder&language=en_US